# Webdriver - Infinite Page loads on submit

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a login page. At certain times (read as intermittent) loading of the home page takes infinite time. In this case, the below command never completes -

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).submit();
```

I am aware of both implicit & explicit waits. 
These waits are applicable only for findElement or DOM related actions but not for submit command ( (Ref: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2606/what-is-seleniums-default-timeout-for-page-loading)

**Debug Log Trace -**

```
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG wire:77 - << "{"name":"submitElement","sessionId":"949f6c8f-a8fc-4e13-b4da-bf6c19c893fe","status":0,"value":""}"
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG DefaultClientConnection:152 - Connection shut down
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG ThreadSafeClientConnManager:272 - Released connection is not reusable.
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG ConnPoolByRoute:434 - Releasing connection [HttpRoute[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]][null]
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG ConnPoolByRoute:679 - Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG SalesForce:153 - Verify next page
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG ThreadSafeClientConnManager:221 - Get connection: HttpRoute[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055], timeout = 120000
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG ConnPoolByRoute:350 - [HttpRoute[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 2000
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG ConnPoolByRoute:523 - No free connections [HttpRoute[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]][null]
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG ConnPoolByRoute:369 - Available capacity: 2000 out of 2000 [HttpRoute[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]][null]
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG ConnPoolByRoute:549 - Creating new connection [HttpRoute[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]]
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG DefaultClientConnectionOperator:145 - Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7055
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG RequestAddCookies:132 - CookieSpec selected: best-match
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG RequestAuthCache:75 - Auth cache not set in the context
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG DefaultHttpClient:643 - Attempt 1 to execute request
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG DefaultClientConnection:264 - Sending request: GET /hub/session/949f6c8f-a8fc-4e13-b4da-bf6c19c893fe/title HTTP/1.1
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "GET /hub/session/949f6c8f-a8fc-4e13-b4da-bf6c19c893fe/title HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG wire:63 - >> "[\r][\n]"
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG headers:268 - >> GET /hub/session/949f6c8f-a8fc-4e13-b4da-bf6c19c893fe/title HTTP/1.1
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG headers:271 - >> Accept: application/json, image/png
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG headers:271 - >> Cache-Control: no-cache
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG headers:271 - >> Host: 127.0.0.1:7055
15 May 2013 16:42:08 DEBUG headers:271 - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Basically DefaultClientConnection does not receive a 200 OK & the command just hangs.

Looking for a solution to close the browser in case of no response from the browser for a **submit command** after waiting for a specific duration.

Comment: you mean like driver.close()?

Comment: anything. I would just want to step into the next statement in case of this scenario after a specific wait

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the id "Login" is that of a form.

Could you instead select the form's submit button (assuming one exists) and call .click() on the button, rather than calling .submit() on the form?

And then you should be able to use implicit or explicit waits.

EDIT:

After submitting the form, you can make a custom method to wait for the response, and close the browser after timing out, if necessary.

```
        int tryCount = 0;
        boolean desiredResponseReceived = false;
        while (desiredResponseReceived == false && tryCount < 20) {
            String statusText = (String) js.executeScript("return xhr.statusText;");
            if (statusText.indexOf("200") != -1) {
                desiredResponseReceived = true;
            }
            else {
                Thread.sleep(250);
                tryCount++;
            }
        }

        if (desiredResponseReceived == false) {
            driver.quit();
        }
```

As written, this method will close the browser if "200" doesn't appear in the xhr response within 5 seconds. (because it checks every 250 milliseconds, 20 times, before it finally reaches the `if (desiredResponseReceived == false)` and closes the browser).

Comment: Tried the click option. Same result with either click() or submit(). No change n behavior

Comment: I edited my answer to wait for "200" in the response and then timeout.